# How sort function works on vector of pair of pairs of integer?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, c++14

Given

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, std::pair<int,int>> a;
std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
```

How is `std::sort` function going to sort this type of vector? Is there any generalization for further cascading of pairs?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What are you confused about?

Answer (score 2):

1. `std::sort` uses `operator<` unless specified otherwise.
2. According to the documentation of `std::pair`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Comparison operators, such as `<` are defined as the lexicographical equivalents:

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically, that is, **compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements**.

In your case, this logic will be applied recursively at each pair level.

Comment: `std::sort` does not default to `std::less<>`

Comment: Check it out, you are right, it goes straight to `operator<`. I had assumed an extra layer of indirection for some reason. Fixing my answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will sort by first element of the first pair of pairs. In another word, the most left value of pair of pairs.

See this simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> Pair;
typedef pair<Pair, Pair> PPair;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& in, pair<int, int> p)
{
    in << '(' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ')';
    return in;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<PPair> vPP;
    PPair pp1(Pair(123, 2), Pair(8, 7));
    PPair pp2(Pair(33, 22), Pair(88, 77));
    PPair pp3(Pair(333, 222), Pair(888, 777));

    vPP.push_back(pp1);
    vPP.push_back(pp3);
    vPP.push_back(pp2);

    std::sort(vPP.begin(), vPP.end());

    vector<PPair>::const_iterator cit;
    for (cit = vPP.begin(); cit < vPP.end(); cit++) {
        cout << (*cit).first << (*cit).second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let our vector be Q

```
vector <pair<int,pair<int,int>>> Q;
```

Then for Sorting

```
sort(Q.begin(),Q.end(),compare);
```

Compare function result the boolean as per the desired condition
i.e This will sort the vector in

> Ascending order

```
bool compare(pair<int,pair<int,int>> a,pair<int,pair<int,int>> b)
{
    if(a.second.first<=b.second.first)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

> Descending order

```
bool compare(pair<int,pair<int,int>> a,pair<int,pair<int,int>> b)
{
    if(a.second.first>=b.second.first)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

So,you can design condition as per your requirement.